# Pick 3 elements from dictionary according to some filters

Tags: python, ansible, jinja2

I have a list of dictionaries:

```json
"my_dict": [
  {"disk": "disk1", "size": 600, "controller": "sc1"},
  {"disk": "disk2", "size": 700, "controller": "sc2"},
  {"disk": "disk3", "size": 600, "controller": "sc1"},
  {"disk": "disk4", "size": 500, "controller": "sc3"},
  ...
  ...
]
```

There are lots of elements in this list and i need to pick 3 of them to make a raid1 disk with a spare.

Constraints for choosing 3 disks:

- Disk sizes should be smallest.
- Disk sizes should be equal.
- Controllers should be the same.

How can i filter the elements and select 3 disks with to above constraints? I've sorted the disks according to their sizes and controllers with sort() filter. But this doesn't guarantee that the first 3 disks would be at the same size and have the same controller.

Thank you.

Comment: The most straightforward way here is probably to create a [custom filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_plugins.html#developing-filter-plugins)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an illustration of my recommendation in comments, here is an example of a custom filter which goes slightly further than your requirement. It will let you select `n` disks (default being 3) with a minimal size for the disk (default being 0 i.e. the smallest disks available for the previous number of disks). Note that if no disk match the criteria, the filter returns an empty list.

You can read the [documentation for custom filters](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_plugins.html#developing-filter-plugins) where you will learn more on how to develop and distribute them if you need to share with a team. For this example, I used the most straightforward method and added my filter in a `filter_plugins/` directory adjacent to my test playbook which gives the following directory structure

```
 $ tree
.
├── filter_plugins
│   └── raid_disk_filters.py
└── playbook.yml
```

This is the `filter_plugins/raid_disk_filters.py` file. It defines a single filter called `smallest_disks_by_controller`

```py
from itertools import groupby


def smallest_disks_by_controller(disk_data, array_size=3, min_disk_size=0):
    """
    Returns a list of disk datas for the smallest disks on the same controller
    :arg disk_data: the list of dicts containing the disk data. each element
      is expected to contain 3 keys: disk, size and controller)
    :arg array_size the number of similar disks to return in the result
    :arg min_disk_size minimum size of the disk to select, smallest one by default
    """

    candidates = []
    keyfunc = lambda x: (x['size'], x['controller'])
    for key, group in groupby(sorted(disk_data, key=keyfunc), keyfunc):
        current_size = key[0]
        current_disks = list(group)
        if current_size >= min_disk_size and len(current_disks) >= array_size:
            candidates = current_disks[:array_size]
            break
    return candidates


class FilterModule(object):
    """Filters to work with disks for raid array creation"""

    def filters(self):
        """Return the filter list."""
        return {
            'smallest_disks_by_controller': smallest_disks_by_controller
        }
```

This is the test `playbook.yml`

```yaml
---
- name: Custom filter demo
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    "my_disks": [{ "disk": "disk1", "size": 900, "controller": "sc1" },{ "disk": "disk2", "size": 700, "controller": "sc2" },{ "disk": "disk3", "size": 600, "controller": "sc1" },{ "disk": "disk4", "size": 500, "controller": "sc3" },{ "disk": "disk5", "size": 600, "controller": "sc1" },{ "disk": "disk6", "size": 700, "controller": "sc2" },{ "disk": "disk7", "size": 600, "controller": "sc1" },{ "disk": "disk8", "size": 500, "controller": "sc3" },{ "disk": "disk9", "size": 600, "controller": "sc1" },{ "disk": "disk10", "size": 700, "controller": "sc2" },{ "disk": "disk11", "size": 600, "controller": "sc1" },{ "disk": "disk12", "size": 500, "controller": "sc3" },{ "disk": "disk13", "size": 600, "controller": "sc1" },{ "disk": "disk14", "size": 700, "controller": "sc2" },{ "disk": "disk15", "size": 600, "controller": "sc1" },{ "disk": "disk16", "size": 500, "controller": "sc3" }]

  tasks:
    - name: Get a list of matching disks
      vars:
        msg: |-
          3 disks, min size: {{ my_disks | smallest_disks_by_controller }}
          3 disks, size >= 700: {{ my_disks | smallest_disks_by_controller(3, 700) }}
          4 disks, min size: {{ my_disks | smallest_disks_by_controller(4) }}
          4 disks, size >=600: {{ my_disks | smallest_disks_by_controller(4, 600) }}
          7 disks, size >=1000: {{ my_disks | smallest_disks_by_controller(7, 1000) }}
      debug:
        msg: "{{ msg.split('\n') }}"
```

Which gives:

```
$ ansible-playbook playbook.yml 

PLAY [Custom filter demo] ***************************************************

TASK [Get a list of matching disks] *****************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "3 disks, min size: [{'disk': 'disk4', 'size': 500, 'controller': 'sc3'}, {'disk': 'disk8', 'size': 500, 'controller': 'sc3'}, {'disk': 'disk12', 'size': 500, 'controller': 'sc3'}]",
        "3 disks, size >= 700: [{'disk': 'disk2', 'size': 700, 'controller': 'sc2'}, {'disk': 'disk6', 'size': 700, 'controller': 'sc2'}, {'disk': 'disk10', 'size': 700, 'controller': 'sc2'}]",
        "4 disks, min size: [{'disk': 'disk4', 'size': 500, 'controller': 'sc3'}, {'disk': 'disk8', 'size': 500, 'controller': 'sc3'}, {'disk': 'disk12', 'size': 500, 'controller': 'sc3'}, {'disk': 'disk16', 'size': 500, 'controller': 'sc3'}]",
        "4 disks, size >=600: [{'disk': 'disk3', 'size': 600, 'controller': 'sc1'}, {'disk': 'disk5', 'size': 600, 'controller': 'sc1'}, {'disk': 'disk7', 'size': 600, 'controller': 'sc1'}, {'disk': 'disk9', 'size': 600, 'controller': 'sc1'}]",
        "7 disks, size >=1000: []"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************
localhost: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Although flowerysong's answer will probably work, to develop a solution with custom filter seems logic.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't the most readable solution, but it works:

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    my_dict:
      - {"disk": "disk1", "size": 600, "controller": "sc1"}
      - {"disk": "disk2", "size": 700, "controller": "sc2"}
      - {"disk": "disk3", "size": 600, "controller": "sc1"}
      - {"disk": "disk4", "size": 500, "controller": "sc3"}
      - {"disk": "disk5", "size": 600, "controller": "sc1"}
      - {"disk": "disk6", "size": 700, "controller": "sc1"}
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ (my_dict_candidates[0] | default([]))[0:3] | default([]) }}"
      vars:
        my_dict_candidates: "{{ my_dict_grouped | map('length') | zip(my_dict_grouped) | selectattr('0', 'gt', 2) | map(attribute='1') }}"
        my_dict_grouped: "{{ my_dict | groupby('controller') | map(attribute='1') | map('groupby', 'size') | flatten(levels=1) | map(attribute='1') }}"
```

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "controller": "sc1",
            "disk": "disk1",
            "size": 600
        },
        {
            "controller": "sc1",
            "disk": "disk3",
            "size": 600
        },
        {
            "controller": "sc1",
            "disk": "disk5",
            "size": 600
        }
    ]
}
```

This is complex enough logic that you might be better off writing a custom filter that implements it instead of trying to use pure Jinja, but the Jinja solution is workable.

In `my_dict_grouped` we're basically doing `groupby() | map(attribute='1')` twice; the map turns the tuple returned from `groupby()` into a simpler list.
This step would be simplified by a filter that supported grouping by multiple things at once, but I'm not aware of one.

In `my_dict_candidates` we figure out the length of each list in `my_dict_grouped`, then select only the ones that satisfy your length requirement. Note that this results in a list which could contain 0 to many results depending on the input data. This is why we have to use default values of empty lists in the final expression where we keep only the first top list (i.e. the smallest available disks) and return only the first three results to use for your raid array.

Comment: I was on the `groupby` track last night when I basically gave up and finally wrote "do that in a custom filter" (which I agree is still the best solution IMO) :) You have tried harder than me and I meanwhile love the result.

Comment: If you add a bit more disks to the example data, this is not totally answering the question, i.e. is returning a list of lists with all disks (not limited to three) for all sizes (not limited to the smallest available one). I fixed that in your above answer. Don't hesitate to review if I was to quick ;)